# Node.js check if multiple files exists with unspecific extension

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I have using node.js to develop a application that grabs an user's avatar file saved I the file system.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.exists(__dirname + "/../public/uploaded/users/" + user.username + "/avatar.png", function(exists){
    if(exists){
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

But this checks only if avatar.png exists. Some avatar file such as avatar.gif or avatar.jpg could also be grabbed.

I know I can put three level of if statements inside if(exists) but I want to know a better way.

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: What about using fs.readdir to list all the files under username folder?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is an easy native method but this library seems like it would do what you are looking for: https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob